# Are extratropical cyclones the same as baroclinic waves?

Tags: meteorology, waves, storms

Are extratropical cyclones the same as baroclinic waves?

I'm aware of the fact that extratropical cyclones form in 'baroclinic zones' and that they start of as waves. But are these what are referred to in papers as baroclinic waves e.g. Czaja et al. 2011; Bony et al. 2015.

Further to this, are these baroclinic waves the same as the Rossby baroclinic waves?

Thank you

Comment: They are both baroclinic phenomena but are not technically the same. See http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/what-are-baroclinic-and-barotropic-waves for more detail on the meaning of baroclinic. There are several types of baroclinic waves and Rossby waves are just one of them.

Comment: Not all the time. Hurricane Sandy, for example, made a transition from being a tropical event (hurricane) to an extratropical cyclone.